# turtle module - displaying a title and adding a background image

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I have recently discovered the world of Python and tried to self teach Python myself.

I have a business background, so almost zero knowledge about the programming & computer science.

Anyways, I am using Linux installed in Chromebook and learning how to use the turtle module to create a simple game.

Currently, my issue is with `wn.title("")` and `wn.bgpic` : the title does not display in the window and the background image just displays a black square.

Please see my code below :

```
import turtle
import os

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("pink")
wn.title("Turtle practice")
wn.setup(width=1000, height=1000)
wn.bgpic('/home/file path/katalk.gif')
```

It would be great if anyone can help me out with this issue.

Comment: can you please post the error

Comment: Please add what error are you getting ?

Comment: The funny thing is that Python does not spit out any error message. Just this one: ============= RESTART: /home/lee/Turtle practice.py =============
>>>

Comment: I have the exact same issue on chromebook. I think it has to do with the container technology on chromebooks.

Answer (score 1):

Your title looks correct. It would display in the title bar of the window, rather than "in" the window. Look at the window's title and you will hopefully see it.

For the graphic, please double check that the .gif file is in the same directory as your code file. You can also try something like "..\katalk.gif" to go up a directory so your code can find the graphic.

Using the below code, I was able to see the title text and have the gif image appear in the turtle window when I had a GIF image in the same directory as the code file.

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("pink")
wn.title("Turtle practice")

wn.setup(width=1000, height=1000)
wn.bgpic("katalk.gif")

turtle.done()
```

Comment: Thank you first for answering my question! I just discovered something interesting. `wn.bgpic("piggy.gif")` works (I tried with a different gif image to double check) but it only displays a shape the image. Now a piggy image is displayed in the window but black even though the image is pink.

Comment: Maybe look into if the graphic you are using for this has transparency.